# android application's retrofit base_url

Tags: android

I want to build an api for an android studio application to make the base url of the retrofit. I am having problems to make the `base_url`. I want to know how I should make the base_url of the retrofit. I am having problems validating the `base_url`. I want to know the procedure to make a base_url for retrofit.

Comment: base url is the starting part of your API url that is same for all requests. Like if http://www.check.com/apis/getProducts and http://www.check.com/apis/saveToken?token=xyz are the APIs then base_url would be http://www.check.com/apis/

Answer (score 1):

If this is my url
http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/top_rated?api_key=12345678910111213

Then base url becomes

http://api.themoviedb.org/

It will be passed in as

```
retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("http://api.themoviedb.org/");
```

and the remaining part will become get or post query

Comment: I have already created an api in the movie database, where I also add an application url as https://www.registration.com . so, what I will use as base url http://api.themoviedb.org/ or https://www.registration.com ? I am confused about it.